# Suppose that S is a nonempty set such that A= LUB S. Let T={2x+1:x element in S}. Prove that LUB T=2A+1

Tags: real-analysis

Can some one please help me get started on this.
I would really like to understand what I am doing.

Suppose that S is a nonempty set such that A= LUB S.

Let $T={2x+1:x \in S}$.

Prove that LUB $T=2A+1$

Answer (score 1):

First, $2\sup S + 1$ is an upper bound of $T$. By the definition of $\sup T$, we must have $$\sup T \leq 2\sup S + 1.$$

Conversely, given $\epsilon >0$ and then there exists $t \in T$ such that  $$\sup T - \epsilon<t .$$

Here $t = 2s + 1$ for some $s \in S$, then $\sup T - \epsilon < 2\sup S + 1$ for any $\epsilon >0$. Therefore we have, $$ \sup T \leq 2\sup S + 1.$$

Answer (score 0):

$2A+1$ is an upperbound of $T$: any $t\in T$ can be written as $t=2s+1$ where $s\in S$. Because $s\leq A$, we have $t=2s+1\leq 2A+1$.

Now suppose that $M$ is any upperbound of $T$, then $\frac{M-1}{2}$ is an upperbound of $S$ so that $\frac{M-1}{s}\geq A$. But this means $M\geq 2A+1$.